# Cannot get JACK Audio/Netjack working over LAN

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, jack

I'm trying to stream low latency audio between 2 raspberry pis. Both gstreamer and ffmpeg induce 2+ second delays for me.

I've played around with Jack Audio and locally on a single pi it seems promising. I can route mic input to a speaker locally and it is almost instantaneous.

However, I have been having trouble getting it to route between devices using Netjack.

```
# ON SERVER
jackd -P70 -p16 -t2000 -dalsa -dhw:1 -p128 -n3 -r44100 -s 

# ON CLIENT
jackd -v -R -P70 -dnetone -i1 -o1 -I0 -O0  -r44100 -p128 -n3

# ON SERVER
jack_netsource -H < ip address of client >
jack_lsp # list availible connection ports

>system:capture_1
>system:playback_1
>system:playback_2
>netjack:capture_1
>netjack:capture_2
>netjack:capture_3
>netjack:playback_1
>netjack:playback_2
>netjack:playback_3

jack_connect system:capture_1 system:playback_1 # this works
jack_connect system:capture_1 netjack:playback_1 # this doesn't work :(
```

Most of the launch options I pulled from here http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/raspberrypi#using_jack. I'll be honest I don't really know what they do.

The client jackd output shows messages like

```
Jack: data not valid
Jack: data not valid
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::Execute : fPollTable i = 1 fd = 6
Jack: JackRequest::Notification
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 3
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 3
netxruns... duration: 139ms
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::Execute : fPollTable i = 1 fd = 6
Jack: JackRequest::Notification
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 3
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 3
```

And the server jack_netsource output looks like

```
current latency 114
current latency 20
current latency 27
current latency 29
current latency 48
current latency 23
current latency 33
current latency 28
current latency 41
current latency 84
current latency 44
```

and the server jackd output looks like

```
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = netjack was not finished, state = Triggered
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
JackEngine::XRun: client = netjack was not finished, state = Triggered
JackEngine::XRun: client = netjack was not finished, state = Triggered
```

I believe the `-dnetone` flag indicates to use Netjack2. Netjack 1, which I've tried with the `-dnet` flag results in a single `Not Connected` message from jack_netsource and:

```
Jack: CatchHost fd = 5 err = Resource temporarily unavailable
Jack: CatchHost fd = 5 err = Resource temporarily unavailable
Jack: CatchHost fd = 5 err = Resource temporarily unavailable
Jack: CatchHost fd = 5 err = Resource temporarily unavailable
Jack: CatchHost fd = 5 err = Resource temporarily unavailable
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::Execute : fPollTable i = 1 fd = 6
```

from the client jackd.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'd like to try this solution for remote online rehearsals.

Comment: I think Jack is super sensitive to network latency. I dont think jack works for remote or wireless setups

Answer (score 1):

Firstly on the raspberry pi, ensure you have mmap enabled ([check here](http://www.flatmax.org/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=16&p=57#p57)).

Once jackd is setup properly, this is the basic method to get jackd2 connected between the master and slave :

On the master ...

```
jackd -d alsa 
jack_load netmanager
```

On the slave ...

```
jackd -r -d net -a ipaddress
```

Should be working at this point, don't forget to connect ports from the netjack to system input and output on the master. You could use the JackPortMonitor or JackPortMonitorGui to autoconnect these on the master for you. In that case, the master startup looks like so :
jackd -d alsa
jack_load netmanager
JackPortMonitorGui